# How do I make a Microsoft Power Point Presentation (ppsx file) launch in my second screen at Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint, power, multiple-monitors

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. I have a presentation that was created with Office 2007 (ppsx file format). When I double click on it, it launches in full screen mode on screen no.1 (I have a dual monitor setup on my machine). However, when I right click on the presentation there is no option to exit the full screen mode or move the window.

I tried to move the window to a specific pixel with an application that can do that (i.e. WinAutomation) which partially worked, but the problem is that the 2 monitors have 2 different resolutions and what is full screen in monitor A, is more than full screen in monitor B.

Is there some application that can help me achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Which Office version are you using to load the presentation?

Comment: The default player for ppsx files (office 2007)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option in the "Slide Show" ribbon (in Office 2007) and then under "Monitors" section, select the second monitor in the "Show Presentation On" field.

Thanks :-)